# Snowflake call a stored procedure inside a loop N times

Tags: sql, loops, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake sproc that runs on 4 hours of data at a time and outputs entries for the first hour.

It has 3 params i.e start_hour, end_hour and output table name.

I want to run this for a full day in a loop and I am trying to write the following looped procedure:

```
create procedure abc_daily()
returns varchar
language sql
as
$$
    declare
        iteration_limit integer default 24;
        counter integer default 0;
    begin
        for i in 0 to iteration_limit do
              
            call abc(
            date_trunc('hour', dateadd(hour, counter, convert_timezone('UTC', '2022-05-10  00:00:00.000 +0000'))),
            date_trunc('hour', dateadd(hour, counter, convert_timezone('UTC', '2022-05-10  04:00:00.000 +0000'))),
           'output table name'

            
            counter := counter + 1;
        end for;
    end;
$$;
```

The date_add will help slide my window till 23rd hour.

However, when I run this create command, I get

```
Syntax error: unexpected 'abc'. (line 19)
```

Looks like it does not recognize the call command.

Could anyone help get this running ?

Do I need to use snowflake.execute here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call does not have a closing parent and semicolon, and your times are not recognized

try:

```
create procedure abc_daily()
returns varchar
language sql
as
$$
declare
    iteration_limit integer default 24;
    counter integer default 0;
begin
    for i in 0 to iteration_limit do
           
        call abc(
            date_trunc('hour', dateadd(hour, counter, convert_timezone('UTC', '2022-05-10  00:00:00.000'))),
            date_trunc('hour', dateadd(hour, counter, convert_timezone('UTC', '2022-05-10  04:00:00.000'))),
           'output table name');
            
        counter := counter + 1;
    end for;
end;
$$;
```

or put the timestamp into a variable, and just reuse it:

```
create procedure abc(f timestamp_ntz, t timestamp_ntz, s text)
returns text
language sql
as
$$
begin
    return f::text || t::text || s;
end;
$$;

create or replace procedure abc_daily()
returns varchar
language sql
as
$$
declare
    iteration_limit integer default 2;
    start_time timestamp_ntz;
begin
    start_time := date_trunc('hour', to_timestamp_ntz('2022-05-10 00:00:00.000'));
    
    for i in 0 to iteration_limit do

        call abc( dateadd(hour, :i, :start_time), dateadd(hour, :i+4, :start_time), 'output table name');
    end for;
end;
$$;


call abc_daily();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Fixed the second option to use start_time as the variable name.

That said when I call abc_daily()  I still get
and error "
SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 45 invalid identifier 'COUNTER'"

on call abc().

Looks like the inner call is not recognizing "Counter" declared outside ? Happens with both options.

Comment: the variables needed to be prefixed with `:`, and then I had to actually run the code....